# How to replace more than one occurrence of a letter in list?

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to make a Hangman game.
To start the verification of the word, I created a list with all the letters in certain word and another list with the '-' symbol for each letter in word. While verifying if the input letter is in the word, this only works when the letter appears only one time. When the letter appears two or more times, it does not work.

```
def game():
    word = list(chosen_word())
    word_to_verify = ['-' for c in word]
    while word != word_to_verify: 
        print('Welcome to the Hangman game! \n',*word_to_verify)
        letter_input = input('\nInsert a letter: ').upper()
        os.system ("clear")
        for letter in word:
            if letter_input == letter :
                word_to_verify[word.index(letter)] = letter
            else: 
                pass
```

The line `word_to_verify[word.index(letter)] = letter` does not work correctly.

Word: A P P L I C A T I O N

Output: A P _ L I C _ T _ O N

Expected output: A P P L I C A T I O N`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this loop:

```
        for letter in word:
            if letter_input == letter :
                word_to_verify[word.index(letter)] = letter
```

`word.index(letter)` will always return the *first* index of `letter` in `word`, so if there are multiple occurrences of `letter`, you'll be setting that first index twice in `word_to_verify`.  That's why after the loop is finished, the first occurrence has been replaced, but the other(s) remain blank.

If you use `enumerate` in your iteration over `word`, you'll get the index of each individual occurrence of `letter`, and can use that index in `word_to_verify`:

```
        for i, letter in enumerate(word):
            if letter_input == letter :
                word_to_verify[i] = letter
```

Note that `else: pass` does nothing and you can just remove it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was enough for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

### `word.index()` always returns the *first* occurrence of the letter in the word.

It is *not* a drop-in replacement for indexing.

You should use brackets to index into the list instead:

```py
for index, letter in enumerate(word):
    if letter_input == letter:
        word_to_verify[index] = letter
```